# jqGrid Toolbar Searching on Decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid with toolbar searching enabled. I have configured my search option as `'eq'`. However, when I input a decimal number on the search bar, the valid record does not show.

For example:
When I input `12`, the record with `12.00` shows, this is correct.
When I input `12.50` the record with `12.50` does not show, this is incorrect.

I experimented with `sorttype` as number, `formatter` with decimal places, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Grid definition:

```
$("#productListingGrid").jqGrid({
    datastr: products,
    datatype: 'jsonstring',
    jsonReader: {
        root: 'products',
        repeatitems: false,
        cell: 'products.branches',
        id: 'productNumber'
    },
    loadonce: true,
    // -1 no longer works: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/317
    rowNum: 10000,
    height: 580,
    width: 1250,
    colNames: columnNames,
    colModel: columnModel,
    sortname: 'productNumber',
    sortorder: "asc",
    caption: 'PRODUCT LIST',
    headertitles: true,
    altRows: true,
    altclass: 'gridStripe',
    gridview: true,
    footerrow: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    shrinkToFit: false
});
```

My column model definition:

```
{ name: 'totalValue' , width:55, align:'right', formatter: 'currency', searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']} }
```

Code to enable the toolbar search:

```
grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {searchOnEnter: false});
```

May I know if this is a current limitation?

Thank you very much.

Note:
I'm currently using the following:

```
jQuery - 1.9.1
jQuery UI - 1.10.2
jqGrid - 4.4.5
```

Comment: could you add some JavaScript code which you use?

Comment: @Oleg I've added some code. Anything specific you need to see?

Comment: @Oleg I've got it to work by setting the sorttype! I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work by setting the `sorttype` value as `'float'`.

From

```
{ name: 'totalValue' , width:55, align:'right', formatter: 'currency', searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']} }
```

to

```
{ name: 'totalValue' , width:55, align:'right', sorttype:'float', formatter: 'currency', searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']} }
```

I find it quite counter-intuitive to set a sort type for searching to work correctly. It could have been better to have a data type instead.